# Rails join on user column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to get all Activities related to users of the same school (a string on the user object), but the error I'm getting is this:

> Can't join 'Activity' to association named 'users'; perhaps you
>   misspelled it?

**activity_controller.rb**

```
@school = current_user.school
@bathroom = Activity.includes(:users).where(name: 'Bathroom').where( :user => { :school => @school} )
```

and the schema:

```
  create_table "activities", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "student_id"
    t.string   "status"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.index ["student_id"], name: "index_activities_on_student_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_activities_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "grade"
    t.string   "school"
    t.integer  "maxout"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Not `users` but `user` because `Activity` belongs to `User`

```
@bathroom = Activity.includes(:user).where(name: 'Bathroom').where( :users => { :school => @school} )
```

But `User` has many `activities` so `User.includes(:activities)`

Of course, you have to provide associations:

```
class Activity
  belongs_to :user

class User
  has_many :activities
```

Comment: Now I'm getting `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Activities#school  SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: user.school`

Comment: Try `Activity.joins(:user)` instead of `includes`

Comment: `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: user.school: SELECT "activities".* FROM "activities" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "activities"."user_id" WHERE "activities"."name" = ? AND "user"."school" = ?`

Comment: Try this `Activity.includes(:user).where(name: 'Bathroom').where( :users => { :school => @school} )` . There is `where(:users` is name of the user's table, not name of the association.

Comment: That's it. Thank you!